# Export After effects shape into Illustrator vector

Tags: vector, export, effects, after-effects

Is it possible to convert the native vector shapes created in After Effects into adobe Illustrator or Eps etc? Tried exporting as SWF but still it converts into raster graphics and loses vector data.

Even if 3rd party scripts are available, please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

One of the simplest ways of doing this, if you have Illustrator handy, is to turn on Illustrator's AICB support in preferences ("Clipboard Handling"), with "Preserve Paths" on. Then you can copy all the masks in a layer and paste them into a document in Illustrator.

If you're working with masks on Solids, the masks are fairly easy to copy. With Shape Layers, it is a little more tricky; you have to at least start with the path of the shape selected. It might be worth converting shape layer paths to masks on solids first. There's a script over at aescripts.com for that.

Answer (score 0):

highlight literally just frame 0 from each Mask Path (don't just select all keyframes across the timeline) then holding shift to get the first frame of all shape layers or do one at a time and then paste that into Illustrator.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to use some icons in a video but needed them as vectors as well for print.

so I chose the frame I wanted to use in AE, composition - save frame as- I chose PS file -then I opened it in Illustrator and image traced it. Because I had simple shapes on a transparent background it worked beautifully.

15 seconds from an AE robot to an AI robot